# Definition of randomly generate in the parallelepiped

Tags: protocol-design, randomness

I am reading the [CLT13] [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/183.pdf) regarding multilinear maps over the integers and I have some troubles in understanding what the following random generation means:

> The vectors of the matrix $r_i \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ are randomly and independently chosen from the half-open parallelepiped spanned by some vectors $\pi_1,...,\pi_n \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.

**What I've understood:** Those $r_i$ can be written as $r_i = a_1\pi_1+...+a_n\pi_n$ where each $a_i$ is random in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is it correct?

You might want to search for the word *span* to see exactly what the authors meant in the paper.

Comment: Does **Appendix E** (Uniform Sampling of a Parallelepiped)  of the same paper answers your question in sufficient details ?

Comment: Great @LeoDucas, I do not know how I missed that. The actually answer is in Appendix **E** of the original paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@LeoDucas already commented](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46594/definition-of-randomly-generate-in-the-parallelepiped#comment104033_46594), the answer is contained in Appendix E (page 22) of the same paper:

> [image: screenshot of Appendix E]